# Session array is not setting up in redirected page

Tags: php

I am Setting up a session variable and it is setting up on current page but when it is redirect the session variable goes to blank.I just need that my session variable starts setting up.i have also tested these code on local,godaddy and number of server

`

```
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $username=$_REQUEST['username'];
        $password=$_REQUEST['password'];
        $login_user=select('admin','username="'.$username.'"and password="'.MD5($password).'"');
        $get_username_result=@mysql_num_rows($login_user);
        $login_user_exe=@mysql_fetch_array($login_user);

        if($get_username_result==1){
        $_SESSION=array();
        $_SESSION['admin']=$login_user_exe['username'];
        $_SESSION['admin_id']=$login_user_exe['id'];

        echo '<script>window.location.href="index.php"</script>';
        }
        else{
        $msg="Invalid username or password";
        }
        }
        ?>
```

`
config.php

```
<?php
                // This is for Mysql Database Connection String File for Remote Machine

                if(!isset($_SESSION)){
                    session_start();
                }
                $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ('Error Connectiong to mysql: '.mysql_error());
                $dbname = "abc";
                mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn) or die ("Select Error: ".mysql_error());

                    function select($table,$where='1'){
                     $query="SELECT * FROM ".$table." where ".$where."";
                    $query1=mysql_query($query);
                    return $query1;
                    }
                    function update($table,$set='1',$where=1){
                     $query="UPDATE ".$table." SET ".$set." Where ".$where."";
                    $query1=mysql_query($query);
                    return $query1;
                    }

                    function insert($table,$set=array()){
                     $column='id=UUID(),';
                    foreach($set as $key => $value) {
                    $column.=$key.'= "'.$value.'",';
                    }
                    $column=rtrim($column, ",");
                     $query="INSERT INTO $table SET $column";
                    $query1=@mysql_query($query);
                    return $query1;
                    }

                    function update1($table,$set=array(),$id){
                     $column='';
                    foreach($set as $key => $value) {
                    $column.=$key.'= "'.$value.'",';
                    }
                    $column=rtrim($column, ",");
                     $query="UPDATE $table SET $column WHERE id='$id'";
                    $query1=@mysql_query($query);
                    return $query1;
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: You're not calling session_start() in your first file. No started session, no preserved data. And you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so sit back and have a fun time when your server gets pwn3d.

Comment: Things aren't functioning as intended and you're suppressing errors with `@`. Read username outloud, please.

Comment: Not to mention there is no `session_write_close()`

Comment: @Mic1780:  Definitely not required.

Answer (score 1):

You did not started the session.

Use `session_start();` in the first file...

Answer (score 1):

Add the session_start(); code at the start of first line without any beginning white space.
this resolved my problem.